# Google App Engine Monetization with Youtube API

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube

I run a website that is hosted through `Google App Engine` which is a custom youtube search engine.  It is hosted through `Google App Engine`.  The Youtube videos are embedded into my website and I recently started to run an ad page when the user first goes to my website.  I want to comply with all Youtube's terms, so I am curious if anyone is in the same situation.  Did you have any issues with Youtube?  I don't want any issues and can always remove my ads if need be.

I have been reading the TOS [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?csw=1):  and I have read that the `Google restrictions Adsense`(which I am not running).

[motionpicker.com](http://motionpicker.com) is the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.